# Is there any convention on how to use OR in URL query parameters?

Tags: http, web, frontend, backend

I have the following URI:

```
example.com/api/records/?mode=timeline&ordering=-date_debut&page_size=50&date_debut=notnull&deadline=notnull
```

What I want is to change `date_debut` and `deadline` to be returned if any of them is `notnull`.

From:

```
date_debut=notnull&deadline=notnull
```

To something like:

```
date_debut=notnull||deadline=notnull
```

How I am able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

When HTML forms build query strings, the parameters are ALWAYS delimited by `&`. When server side libraries parse query strings, they do so based on `&` delimiters. When you try to use `||` in a query string, your example will actually be parsed as a single name value pair named `date_debut` with a value of `notnull||deadline=notnull`.

That being said, if you are generating the query strings with your own code, and parsing them with your own code, you can do as you want.  `|` is not a reserved character in URLs, so you could use it as in your example. You'd just have to write your own query string parser.

If you wanted to use the usual semantics of query strings I might suggest using an additional parameter that says what type of boolean operation to apply.  Something like `date_debut=notnull&combine=or&deadline=notnull`.